# (Corona SDK) Call function once from an "enterFrame" function

Tags: function, lua, runtime, coronasdk

I'm wondering how it would be possible to call a function once from an "enterFrame" function in Corona SDK.

Let's say i have:

```
local function funa()
    i = i+1
    funb()
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", funa)
```

Besides wanting 'i' to be incremented each frame, I also want to run "funb", but only one time instead of one time for each frame, but I can't find out how to do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the simpler and more obvious solution of using a global variable to keep track of this, you can use a closure.  Example:

```
local
function funa()
  local run_already = false
  local i = 0
  return function()
           i = i+1
           if not run_already then
             funb()
             run_already = true
           end
         end
end

funa = funa()
funa()
funa()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local run_flag = false

local function funa()

i = i+1
  if not run_flag then 
   funb()
   run _flag = true
 end 
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", funa)
```

Now  i will incremented each frame , but function will be called once.